# define the reals in a non-archimedean elementary extension of the real field.

Tags: logic, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

Can it be done?
We have the real field $(\Bbb R,+,-,\times,0,1,<)$, of course $(0,1,-,<)$ are definable using the rest.
We take an elementary non-archimedean extension. Can we define the original set of reals in it?

Comment: What's an elementary extension? Ah, it's a logic term... [link for others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_extension)

Comment: Define in the language of rings? (which, by the way, need not include $-$, as that is definable from $+$.)

Comment: @rschwieb: It's a model of the same theory, which $\Bbb R$ is an elementary submodel of it. That is to say, if the large field satisfies a formula $\exists x\varphi(x,u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ where $u_i$ are real numbers (from $\Bbb R$ that is), then you can find a witness for that $x$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot: You have the supremum property for bounded *definable* sets, since this is first-order and your extension is elementary. If $\mathbb R$ is definable, it would be bounded (by any infinite element of the field). So there would be a "least" infinite number.

Comment: This argument makes an excellent example of using elementarity to show that a set cannot be defined. I'm going to use it as an example in the next semester! (Although I doubt I'm going to remember that by then...) :-)

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: what do you mean by the supremum property? And how is it a first-order notion?

Comment: @RobArthan A set $R$ is definable in the field $\mathbb F$ iff there is a formula $\phi(x,\vec t)$ in the language specified in the question, and parameters $\vec s\in \mathbb F$, such that $R=\{r\in\mathbb F\mid \mathbb F\models \phi[r,\vec s]\}$. (Cont.)

Comment: @RobArthan The set $\mathbb R$ satisfies the least upper bound property (which is not a first order property), and therefore, it satisfies of any formula as above that "for all $\vec t$, if there is an $N$ such that for all $s$, $\phi(s,\vec t)\to s\le N$, then there is an $M$ such that for all $s$, $\phi(s,\vec t)\to s\le M$ and for any $K<M$ there is an $r$ such that $\phi(r,\vec t)$ and $r>K$." (Cont.)

Comment: @RobArthan Since this statement is first order, if $\mathbb F$ is an elementary extension of $\mathbb R$, then $\mathbb F$ also satisfies the statement. Note that this holds for any formula $\phi$. Were $\mathbb R$ definable in such a non-arquimedean extension, say by $\phi$ and $\vec s$ (where the tuple $\vec s$ may include nonstandard elements), then $\mathbb F$ would satisfy that there is a least upper bound for $\mathbb R$, because $\mathbb R$ is bounded in $\mathbb F$, and the statement from the previous comment holds. (Cont.)

Comment: @RobArthan  This, however, is false, because any bound $b$ would be infinite, but then $b-1$ would be infinite as well.

Comment: (By the way, this is just an example of the *overspill* principle.)

Answer (score 3):

The first-order theory of the real numbers coincides with the first-order theory of real closed fields (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field). This theory is O-minimal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory) which implies that the definable subsets of such a field, $L$ say, comprise finite unions of points and open intervals. A proper subfield of a real closed field $L$ cannot have this form. (Because if $K$ is a definable subfield, then $\pm 1, \pm 1/2, \pm 1/3, \ldots \in K$, so $K$ contains infinitely many members of the closed interval $[-1, 1]$ (i.e., $\{x \in L \mid -1 \le x \le 1\}$), hence by O-minimality, $K$ must contain $[-1, 1]$. But then $K$ contains $x$ or $1/x$ for any $x$, so $K$ is the whole field $L$).

Comment: "A proper subfield cannot have this form" because...

Comment: (A proof of this goes by arguing that, in $\mathbb R$, no proper subfield has this form, which can be easily established from the Archimedean property. One then transfers this result using elementary equivalence. Note that this is not a first-order statement, rather, an infinite family of statements, one for each possible ordering of a finite union of points and intervals. Do you know a more direct argument?)

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: I have added a direct argument to my answer.

Comment: That's simpler than what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it does not quite follow as written that $K $ needs to contain $[-1,1] $. What you get is that it almost contains a neighborhood $N $ of 0, which in turn implies that  $K $ contains all of $\mathbb R $ by consider the closure of $N $ under addition.

Comment: (Please ignore the word "almost"; it is a vestige of what I was typing first.)

Comment: I don't see your point: when I write $[-1, 1]$ I am not referring to the interval in the real numbers but the interval in the real closed field under discussion. It is certainly not the case that any real closed field contains the real numbers $\Bbb{R}$. (The algebraic real numbers provide a minimal counterexample.)

Comment: Well, my point is simply that your argument as written is incomplete, and that it can be completed as I suggested. Since your last comment suggests you are not discussing definable subfields of $\mathbb R $, then a few details seem to still be missing from your sketch.

Comment: My argument was complete, but you misunderstood it. I have attempted to clarify the point that you failed to understand.

Comment: I understood the argument. $[-1,1] \smallsubsetminus\{1/\pi\} $ is a definable set that contains all $1/n $ and all $-1/n $, and does not contain the whole interval.

Comment: $\pi$ is not definable in the language over the signature given in the question and may not exist in the real closed field $L$ in my answer. You really are missing the point of my answer (which applies to arbitrary real closed fields and not just extensions of $\Bbb{R}$).

Comment: Rob, the definitions may involve parametets. Replace $1/\pi $ with any generic element of the field. And, again, no, I am not missing the point. I was trying to point out a small issue with the sketch you gave. You feel there are no issues with it, that's fine, we can leave it at that.